# \clearpage does not work when adding tocloft

Tags: tocloft, books, clearpage

I am using `scrbook` and using `\begin{titlepage}` and `\end{titlepage}` to make the title of the book. After that, added `\clearpage` before making `\tableofcontents` so that toc do not show on the second page, but on the third page.

This works with no problem, except when adding the package `tocloft`  which I need to make local table of contents.

Is this a known issue? How to make `\clearpage` not be ignored and still use this package? Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}%    
\usepackage{tocloft}    
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
  \begin{titlepage}
     \begin{center}
        \textbf{My book title here}
     \end{center}
   \end{titlepage}

\clearpage %add another \clearpage after this also have no effect

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % for main TOC, only show chapter/section
\tableofcontents    
\mainmatter    
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{first section}    
\end{document}
```

Compiled using `lualatex foo.tex` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

commenting out the `\usepackage{tocloft}` now a blank page shows between the title and table of contents as expected.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

TL 2019 on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment `titlepage` adds a `\clearpage` at its end. So an additional explicit `\clearpage` does not add an additional empty page - neither with nor without package `tocloft`. But without page `tocloft` the TOC is added as chapter and uses a `\cleardoubleoddpage` before its start. Therefore you get an empty page between the title page an the TOC, if you remove package `tocloft`.

Disclaimer: The usage of `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.

But if you really want/need to use package `tocloft`, you can add `titles` to the package options of `tocloft`:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}% <- changed
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
  \begin{titlepage}
     \begin{center}
        \textbf{My book title here}
     \end{center}
   \end{titlepage}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % for main TOC, only show chapter/section
\tableofcontents    
\mainmatter    
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{first section}    
\end{document}
```

Or you can use `\cleardoublepage` or `\cleardoubleoddpage` before the TOC:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
  \begin{titlepage}
     \begin{center}
        \textbf{My book title here}
     \end{center}
   \end{titlepage}

\cleardoubleoddpage% <- changed
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents    
\mainmatter    
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{first section}    
\end{document}
```

You could add some invisible content to the page between title page and TOC. Then it is possible to use `\clearpage`:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
  \begin{titlepage}
     \begin{center}
        \textbf{My book title here}
     \end{center}
   \end{titlepage}

\mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage% <- changed
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents    
\mainmatter    
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{first section}    
\end{document}
```